# Instantiate in circle objects look to center

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

A little bit confused - math is really not my strong point, so I'm not sure how to achieve.

Currently the objects instantiate, but I have no control over the distance from center or the rotation of each spawned object

```
public void instantiateInCircle()
{
   for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++)
   {
    float radius = spawnDistance;
    float angle = i * Mathf.PI * 2f / radius;
    Vector3 newPos = transform.position + (new Vector3(Mathf.Cos(angle) * radius, spawnHeight, Mathf.Sin(angle) * radius ));

    //Rotate objects to look at the center
    GameObject instantiatedObject = Instantiate(itemToSpawn, newPos, Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, 0));
    instantiatedObject.transform.LookAt(spawnAroundThis.transform);

    //How to adjust the width of the radius, how far away from the center?

    //Parent instantiated objects to disk
    instantiatedObject.transform.parent = spawnAroundThis.transform;
    instantiatedObject.transform.localScale = new Vector3(scale, scale, scale);
    }
}
```

How to make the distance adjustable, move cubes in closer to center...?
[image]

Comment: if the objects are rotated and maintain a "looking out" and are positioned so that if at "north" they point north and then rotate, to move them out you would move them along the forward vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, you do not access the instantiated object, but the prefab instead. Cache the object and call the `LookAt` on them.

Since I do not know what type `itemToSpawn` is, I assumed it is a `GameObject`. You may want to use your type instead.

```
GameObject instantiatedObject = Instantiate(itemToSpawn, newPos, Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, 0));
instantiatedObject.transform.LookAt(spawnAroundThis.transform);
```

Comment: Thankyou Max that surely solves the rotating the object problem :)
Now somehow I need to be able to control the distance/size of the radius.
halfway there :) - thanks again!

Comment: This is a completely different question compared to what you asked initially. Why don't you create a new question for that topic.  
Regarding the control of the radius, you can give it to the method as parameter instead of setting it as "amount" which doesn't make any sense to me. The movement of the objects should be handled by the objects in my opinion.

Comment: sure I have changed the title to reflect more accurately the solution to rotating the object to look at the center...thanks for that, it helps!
now to find how to get distance :) thanks again and have a great day

Answer (score 0):

If you want to control the distance from center of the rotation:

```
for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++)
{
    float radius = spawnDistance;
    float angle = i * Mathf.PI * 2f / (float)amount; // divide by amount, NOT radius
    // manipulate radius here as you want
    Vector3 newPos = transform.position + (new Vector3(Mathf.Cos(angle) * radius, spawnHeight, Mathf.Sin(angle) * radius ));
    ...
}
```